# Drawing bitmaps in Flash creates an alpha channel issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, drawing, alpha-transparency

I'm creating a drawing app in Flash with AS3.  The "brushstroke" is created with a bitmap.  This code seems to work fine when the brushstrokes are spread out.  [SEE IMAGE 1]

But when the same stroke is clicked repeatedly in the same spot, it's evident the the brushstroke is not only adding alpha but deleting it as well. [SEE IMAGE 2]  I want to eliminate the "box" shape surrounding the brushstroke.

The code snippet that I'm currently using is below.  Is there such thing as an "alpha add" so that this alpha subtraction doesn't occur?  The brushstroke blob is here for reference. [SEE IMAGE 3]

1
[Drawing app http://theluv.is/downloading/drawImg1.png](http://theluv.is/downloading/drawImg1.png)
2
[Drawing app http://theluv.is/downloading/drawImg2.png](http://theluv.is/downloading/drawImg2.png)
3
[Drawing app http://theluv.is/downloading/brushBlob.png](http://theluv.is/downloading/brushBlob.png)

```
function stampImage(){
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.translate(mouseX + brushOffsetX, mouseY + brushOffsetY);

maskSprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(blob, matrix, false, false);
maskSprite.graphics.drawRect(mouseX + brushOffsetX, mouseY + brushOffsetY, blob.width, blob.height);
maskSprite.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: After thinking about this one for a bit (because I'm trying to do a decent free "paint" app in AIR for android right now too) I'm still not quite sure how to fix the issue.  But I've found in my own project that using a bunch of drawCircle calls ended up affecting performance, using a bitmapData instead and using fillRect has worked for my basic purposes so far, to achieve a brush I was planning on copyPixels, but haven't fleshed this out yet.  http://blog.leeburrows.com/2010/09/bitmapdata-basics-1/ <-Maybe that will help though

Comment: In particular there's mention of a mergeAlpha property when doing a copyPixels call, or possibly using the copyChannel call to copy the RGB but not the A... but haven't actually tried any of this just some guesses.

Comment: Paint:) is really nice functionality to build - I guess everyone was trying or did it at some point - here is mine: http://greladesign.com/colourbook/index.html. Are you saying that your paint operates only on drawing API instead of bitmap? drawing will really affect performance - it will be slowing down with the amount of drawn elements - so abandon it. I started with the same idea, then it evolved in hybrid solution where the vector (drawing API) brush and lines were drawn on the bitmap - so after releasing mouse what ever was drawn was rasterized to bitmap, but best solution is bitmapdata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [BitmapData.copyPixels](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels%28%29) method. You can specify alpha blending there.
Of course you'll have to modify your code. First of all you'll have a canvas bitmapdata.

```
var bmpd:BitmapData;
```

And to draw it on screen you just create a Bitmap object.

```
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(...);
bmp.bitmapData = bmpd;
addChild(bmp);
```

When you want to draw something use

```
bmpd.copyPixels(blob, blob.rect, new Point(x,y), null, null, true);
```

Where blob is a BitmapData with your brush texture.

The problem will be if you want to rotate brush texture. In this case use [BitmapData.draw](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29).

Comment: It's frustrating how simple this solution was!  And how much better the performance.  Thanks all.